# Небольшой анализ правильности ввода

Tags: c++

С клавиатуры вводится число (int), это число означает потом размер массива, естественно если было введено число <= 0, то нужно сообщить, что введенное число не верное, если введены буквы - аналогично.

```
cout << "Введите размеренность массива:";
cin >> n;

while(n <= 0)
{
    cout << "Вы ввели не верный размер. Введите размеренность массива: ";
    cin >> n;
}
```

Если я ввожу отрицательное число - всё нормально, а вот если ввожу буквы, то тогда цикл становится бесконечным и просто игнорирует cin >> n;
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту маленькую проблемку?

Comment: Не.. Всётаки помогло лишь отчасти, если вводить текст, то всёравно ошибка.. Эх.. Ну да ладно, завтра разберусь...

Comment: Что помогло отчасти? У меня пример собирается и доходит до <pre>cout\<\<n</pre> только в случае ввода числового значения.

Comment: Аналогично

Comment: У меня вылетает ошибка, т.е. не так как у вас...

Comment: Какая? Давайте подробнее, иначе сложно помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void)
{    
    std::cout<<"ENTER number please"<<std::endl;
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    while(n<=0)
    {
        std::cin.clear(); // вся работа производится в этой и следующей строчке
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        std::cout<<"ERROR, Enter number again"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>n;
    }
    std::cout<<"You've entered "<<n<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp> ./a.out 
ENTER number please
sfdsf
ERROR, Enter number again
-10
ERROR, Enter number again
10
You've entered 10
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp>
```

и еще:

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp> ./a.out 
ENTER number please
10
You've entered 10
gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, однако у меня выдает несколько ошибок при компиляции(3)..
Все они указывают на эту строку: cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
Ошибки:[br]
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '::'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: Компилятор какой? M$? Я компилировал g++ и все было ОК.

Comment: "Компилятор какой? M$? "
Да, MS Visual Studio..

Comment: Попробуйте для начала <pre>cin.ignore(256, '\n');</pre>

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

P.S.: А как вы до этого догадались? Как научиться разбираться как вы?
Просто, например, в C# там Intellisense подсказывает параметры "более понятно", а тут в С++ чуть по другому, и параметры ф-ции ignore, как и её описание.. не очень впечатляют..

Comment: Надо учиться ресурсами интернета. Учитывая, что С++ появился не вчера, то понятно, что Вы скорее всего проходитесь по тем же граблям, что и другие люди. В качестве хорошего подспорья рекомендую ресурсы http://www.cplusplus.com/ и MSDN
PS: вместо 256 лучше подставить боооооольшое значение - максимально возможную длину снимаемой с cin строки. Это и делает <pre>numeric_limits\<streamsize\>::max()</pre> - подставляет вместо себя эту величину.

Comment: Подозреваю это MSVC (судя по формату ошибок) и его заголовочные файлы, которые определяют макрос max. Попробуйте где-нибудь прямо перед функцией main вставить следующее:

     #if defined(max)
     #  undef max
     #endif

Answer (score 0):

Бросьте Вы этот cin. Грабли, на которые все наступают.

Сейчас меня начнут бить, но посоветую использовать scanf() из С ,без плюсов.

Comment: Только работает scanf ненамного лучше
<pre>gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp> ./a.out
ENTER number please
10
You've entered 10

gaal@linux-lybs:~/EULER/cpp> ./a.out
ENTER number please
fdfdsf
You've entered -1217256700</pre><p>
Получается, что в одном, что в другом случае нужно принимать доп.меры для обеспечения корректности ввода. Хотя, соглашусь, на плюсах это выглядит монструозно. К тому же мешать scanf/printf и cin/cout, насколько я помню, нигде не рекомендуется. И со scanf'ом можно наломать дров.

Comment: Стандартные: передача указателя не того, что нужно; неправильная строка форматирования; использования в качестве строки форматирования пользовательского ввода (последнее - для sscanf и аналогов).

Comment: Естественно надо проверять число, возвращаемое scanf() т.е. количество успешно введенных в соответствии с форматом элементов. В случае одного числа: puts ("Enter number"); while (!scanf("%d",&n)) { char line[1000]; fgets(line,1000,stdin); puts("Error. Try again"); } Это сбросит ВСЕ введенные в строке данные. Ну, по большому счету (для очень длинной строки), надо вместо fgets() в цикле посимвольно читать до '\n'.

Comment: почему-то в символе новой строки '\n' бэкслеш пропал.

Comment: '\\n' пробую 2 бэкслеша